# How to "cat" or "less" a libreoffice writer .odt file?

Tags: libreoffice, text-processing

Is there a way to `cat` or `less` a .odt file just as `antiword` does for .doc files?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is using `odt2txt`. Now, this command is provided by two different packages, namely one called [`odt2txt`](https://github.com/dstosberg/odt2txt/) that you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install odt2txt
```

and by the package [`unoconv`](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/unoconv/) (that offers also command-line conversions between more libreoffice formats), that is installed by

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

If you have the two, you can switch between them using the [alternative mechanism](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_the_update_alternatives_command):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config odt2txt
```

If you are using the `odt2txt` provided by the package `odt2txt` you just use

```
odt2txt file.odt
```

if using the `unoconv` provided package you have to use

```
odt2txt --stdout file.odt
```

Pipe them to `less` to have a less-like experience (`odt2txt file.odt | less`)

Notice that if you do not use the `--stdout` option, the unoconv-provided package will write the result in a file called  `file.txt`.

The suggested package by the distribution seems to be the one from the `odt2txt` package (it has a higher default priority in the alternative system); for sure it has less dependencies.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Yes, I've installed the `odt2txt` package and it behaves as it should.

Comment: The problem with `unoconv`, as I have discovered, is that it wants to install an older version of Libre Office if you have a newer one installed. Therefore, stick with `sudo apt install odt2txt`.

Comment: @PaddyLandau I heavily edited the answer, thank for the hint.

Comment: @Rmano You have also taught me about `update-alternatives`, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`odt2txt file.odt`

the source code and compilebale working zip can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/dstosberg/odt2txt/

or installed by 
`sudo apt-get install odt2txt`

Answer (score 7):

You can browse through text without any special utility. ODT file is a renamed zip archive. Unzip it and you will see several files. One of them, `content.xml` contains all text and is `more` or `less` readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `cat` or `less` or `more` an .odt file because it's a binary file. It's actually - as was said earlier - a renamed .zip archive, so you have to extract the `content.xml` file, but that, as it implies, is an XML document, so you have to process it as such to extract the information out of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible with LibreOffice's own command line tool:

```bsh
loffice --convert-to txt f.odt && less f.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

At least since LibreOffice 6.0, the flag `--cat` can be used for this.

```
libreoffice --cat your_file.odt
```

Be aware that LibreOffice Writer must be closed in order for the command to work.