# Will grep or sed search within a .ppt file to find a phrase?

Tags: grep, sed

A large number of .ppt (Powerpoint) files are available to the command line in various directories of a USB drive.  The goal is to find the .ppt file with a case sensitive phrase:

Phrase: 'Return on investment'

It would be preferable if the search mechanism where recursive.  Bonus-round for explanations that with an explanation the trapping mechanism and build-out to recursively searching the disk.  Thank you

## UPDATE

Success thanks to Steeldriver for pointing to helpful search mechanism:

```sh
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

- `-r` or `-R` is recursive,
- `-n` is line number, and
- `-w` stands for match the whole word.
- `-l` (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.

Along with these, `--exclude`, `--include`, `--exclude-dir` or `--include-dir` flags could be used for efficient searching:

- This will only search through those files which have .c or .h extensions:

  ```
  grep --include=\*.{c,h} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```
- This will exclude searching all the files ending with .o extension:

```sh
grep --exclude=*.o -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

- Just like exclude files, it's possible to exclude/include directories through `--exclude-dir` and `--include-dir` parameter. For example, this will exclude the dirs dir1/, dir2/ and all of them matching *.dst/:

```sh
grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,*.dst} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

This works very well for me, to achieve almost the same purpose like yours.

For more options check `man grep`.

Comment: PPT and all non-pure-text formats are binary, so you can't perform text search on them (mostly). So the answer is no.

Comment: With `.pptx` (which is a zipped collection of XML files) it might be possible - by unzipping then searching the `ppt/slides/slide*.xml` files. Similar questions have been asked about `.odt` and `.docx` - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/828586/178692) for example.