# How to edit a .odt file from the terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, text-editor

I work a lot with **LibreOffice** Writer.

I wanted to know if there was a way to edit the text through the terminal?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  This question asks if there's a text-based Terminal utility for editing .odt files.  The other question is about using Terminal to launch a particular .odt file into the full graphical version of LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: IMHO it's probably closer to this [cat command doesn't show the lines of the text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828578/cat-command-doesnt-show-the-lines-of-the-text) - which explains how to unzip an odt file to obtain the underlying `content.xml` file

Comment: The closest thing to what you're looking for is wordgrinder, you can install it executing: `sudo apt install wordgrinder`, [here](https://cowlark.com/wordgrinder/) is the official website of the project, hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`libreoffice` comes with an option to convert an `odt` file to plain text, which then can be edited with your preferred command-line text editor and (if wanted) converted back to `odt`.

1. Convert `document.odt`:

   ```
   libreoffice --convert-to txt document.odt
   ```
2. Edit the file with your preferred text editor, e.g.:

   ```
   gedit document.txt
   nano document.txt
   vim document.txt
   ```
3. Convert it back. The `--convert-to` takes a filename extension as an argument, but you may also specify a filename suffix to prevent `libreoffice` from overwriting the original file (which it does without asking!):

   ```
   libreoffice --convert-to _new.odt document.txt
   ```

For the conversion there's also [`odt2txt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/odt2txt), I'd just try both and compare the results.

If you're using `vim` you can configure it to automatically do the conversion for you in the background, see: [Is it possible to easily work with .odt, .doc, .docx, .rtf, and other non-plain-text formats in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/554/is-it-possible-to-easily-work-with-odt-doc-docx-rtf-and-other-non-plain) The answer there uses `odt2txt`  for the conversion, but it should be possible with `libreoffice --convert-to` as well.

Comment: If anyone, like me, happens across this and tries wrestling this into .vimrc, this is what worked for me 
`autocmd BufReadPost *.odt silent %!pandoc "%" -tmarkdown -o /dev/stdout`

`autocmd BufWritePost *.odt :%!pandoc -f markdown "%" -o "%:r".odt
`

Comment: This method ruins the .odt's format when converting from .txt to .odt if you converted the original .odt to .txt to edit, and convert it back to .odt.

Comment: @user58029 What do you mean by saying “ruins the .odt’s format”? I can’t test it, but I wouldn’t expect text formatting to survive the conversion. If you seek to achieve that, search for conversion to markup languages like markdown or textile instead.

Answer (score 8):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is `wordgrinder`, a terminal-based word processor.

You can install it executing:

```
sudo apt install wordgrinder
```

Here is the official website of the project: https://cowlark.com/wordgrinder/

This is the Github repo:
https://github.com/davidgiven/wordgrinder

And a quick Survival Guide: https://gist.github.com/davidgiven/1aba97e96a9b8f9b573b

If you check the Importing and Exporting sections you will find:

#### Importing

> Imports basic content from ODT files. OpenDocument is complicated and
> hard to parse but WordGrinder will do its best to apply appropriate
> styles. Unsupported features are ignored.

#### Exporting

> This produces an ODT file which can be read by LibreOffice and a
> variety of other major word processors. Character and paragraph styles
> are exported and are mapped to OpenDocument styles called P, H1, H2
> etc.